# How to link a url as a default like localhost in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, server

I have a url which is now https and is ready to be use. But the problem is, I do not know how to use that url as Nodejs backend localhost.

By default, We are using 
`http://localhost:3000/api/thisRoute`

And I want to use that url and it looks like this
`https://api.domainName.com/api/thisRoute`

Current Status:

My backend is deployed in AWS EC2 and already link to that url and I am still using the default in the backend.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an ALB ([Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-application-load-balancer.html)) in AWS and terminate the https connection at the Load Balancer by setting up a [HTTPS listener](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html). Then have it send the request via http to your EC2 Instance on port 3000 via a [target group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-register-targets.html).

**OR**

You could setup a second listener on port 443 in your node.js server (see [https.createServer](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener)) and point the DNS directly to your EC2 Instance IP address. This would require more work but you don't have to pay for a Load Balancer.

Comment: Thanks @Codeseer. I will try this method.